# Flex - Objects within Objects

Tags: arrays, apache-flex, object

So I'm still trying to get my head around Flex and OOP and I am stuck right now. Here is the code I'm currently working with.

```
    var labs:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    var sets:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

    var labsArray:Array = ["ProDPI","WHCC","Tin"];
    var setsArray:Array = [ ["Set01","Set02","Set03","Set04"],["Set11","Set12","Set13","Set14"], ["Set21","Set22","Set23","Set24"] ];

    var objLab:Object = new Object;
    objLab.labName = labsArray[0];
    objLab.setFolders = undefined;
    labs.addItem(objLab);

    for (var i:int = 0; i < setsArray.length; i++) {
        var objSets:Object = new Object;
        objSets.setName = setsArray[i];
        sets.addItem(objSets);
        objLab.setFolders = objSets;
    }
    labFolderList.labelField="labName";
    labFolderList.dataProvider=labs;

    setFolderList.labelField="setFolders";
    setFolderList.dataProvider=sets;
```

The objLab object is returning as I wish it to. The objSets is displaying in my ComboBox as object, Object. The application is ComboBox #1 will be populated by labsArray, which is working. Depending on the selection of [0,1,2] from the array this will call from the sets array the array in the matching position.

Finally, with the selection of the ComboBox#1, the second ComboBox#2 will change to the matching selection.

Any help on how to get the object Objects to rendering correctly would be of great help. Also if my execution is not the best way to do this any direction (links/documentation) I will take as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Bungdaddy can you provide more of the code with regard to the selection change handler on the initial combo box and maybe some of the MXML as well just so I can get a clearer picture of what you're going for, the explanation is pretty good but it will be easier to answer with a bit more code.  Also it appears you have an open for loop above, it's best to copy/paste code into the text editor on stack overflow then highlight all the pasted code and hit the {} button above the text area (explaining as it appears to be cut off).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your original code based on assumptions for what you were trying to accomplish, I added the Array objects directly to the collection being assigned the dataprovider, in this case you should see the output of the .toString() method called on the Array instead of the Object class, the Object class .toString() will output the [object Object] you were seeing in the display.  The Array .toString() method will call .toString() on each element in the array and separate them with commas and surround them with curly braces, very similar to what you have when defining the array.  Alternatively you could create your own class that extends Object and make your own toString method to override the default behavior, using Object is generally not a great practice (there are exceptions to this it's not a hard rule but it tends to be better to use a specific class type, or even better an interface when possible).

```
    var labs:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    var sets:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

    var labsArray:Array = ["ProDPI","WHCC","Tin"];
    var setsArray:Array = [ ["Set01","Set02","Set03","Set04"],["Set11","Set12","Set13","Set14"], ["Set21","Set22","Set23","Set24"] ];

    var objLab:Object = new Object;
    objLab.labName = labsArray[0];
    objLab.setFolders = undefined;
    labs.addItem(objLab);

    for (var i:int = 0; i < setsArray.length; i++) {
        sets.addItem(setsArray[i]);
        objLab.setFolders = setsArray[i];
    }
    labFolderList.labelField="labName";
    labFolderList.dataProvider=labs;

    setFolderList.labelField="setFolders";
    setFolderList.dataProvider=sets;
```

Another alternative aside from making a Class as I explained above is to use the labelFunction instead of the labelField, using a labelFunction each item:Object in the dataProvider will be passed into your custom labelFunction and you can return a string based on whatever logic you see fit.  It would be something along these lines:

```
   setFolderList.labelFunction = myLabelFunction;

   private function myLabelFunction(item:Object):String
   {
       var retString:String = "";
       for(var i:int=0; i<item.setName.length; i++)
       {
            if(i>0)
                retString += ", ";
            retString += item.setName[i];
       }
       return retString;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks @shaunhusain -- these are two great possible answers. I'll have to experiment to see what ends up working the best. Thanks for the detailed explanations. Plus if you have additional Flex resources to recommend, I would greatly appreciate. I am using Flex as an interface with Photoshop panels -- it's been a steep learning curve. -- Depaul Alum here as well!

Comment: @Bungdaddy cool glad that'll work out for ya, and amazed you read my profile, I literally just updated that (was going for badges... damn you SO).  When I was first learning flex the "Flex in a Week" videos were the best introduction, also James Ward, Doug McCune, Ted Patrick (the sencha one not the wikipedia one, programmer not deprogrammer, though the other guy has an interesting story too), and I'm sure lots of others have a lot of good stuff (google any of them links are too long for comments).  I share code on my site though it hasn't been updated (and was never complete) for years.